# How to index pdf, ppt, xl files in lucene (java based or python or php any of these is fine)?

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

Also I want to know how to add meta data while indexing so that i can boost some parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene indexes text not files - you'll need some other process for extracting the text out of the file and running Lucene over that.

Answer (score 4):

There are several frameworks for extracting text suitable for Lucene indexing from rich text files (pdf, ppt etc.)

- One of them is [Apache Tika](http://lucene.apache.org/tika/), a sub-project of Lucene.
- [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) is a more general document handling project inside Apache.
- There are also some commercial alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Apache [Tika](http://lucene.apache.org/tika/index.html). Tika is a toolkit for detecting and extracting metadata and structured text content from various documents using existing parser libraries.

Supported Document Formats

- HyperText Markup Language
- XML and derived formats
- Microsoft Office document formats
- OpenDocument Format
- Portable Document Format
- Electronic Publication Format
- Rich Text Format
- Compression and packaging formats
- Text formats
- Audio formats
- Image formats
- Video formats
- Java class files and archives
- The mbox format

The code will look like this.

Reader reader = new Tika().parse(stream);

Answer (score 1):

see  https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pdfindexer
for a java solution that uses PDFBox and Apache Lucene to split the PDF files page by page to text,
index these text-pages and create a resulting html index file that links to the pages in the pdf sources by using a corresponding open parameter.