# How to convert pdf, ppt, xl, doc files to txt/html files... any opensource tools/codes in php/python/perl available?

Tags: php, file, lucene, format

My end objective is to index documents using lucene. As lucene doesnt support indexing other formats. I want to convert these files to txt/html (lucene indexable file types).
I have a set of documents almost 1000 files of ppt, pdf, doc, xl etc
Please help me

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582951/how-to-index-pdf-ppt-xl-files-in-lucene-java-based-or-python-or-php-any-of-the  . Please see my answer to that question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use OpenOffice headless to convert the files from one format to another, say Excel/Doc to TXT/HTML.

We use a similar process combined with ImageMagick to allow people to upload office documents into a presentation app.

Below are a few examples/tutorials on how to achieve this:

**Setup OpenOffice**

http://code.google.com/p/openmeetings/wiki/OpenOfficeConverter

**JOD Converter** (Java)

http://artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter

**PyOD Converter** (Python)

http://artofsolving.com/opensource/pyodconverter

If you need any further help with OOo feel free to ask

Good luck :)

Answer (score -1):

You now (2022) have a python opensource that does this: https://github.com/shakiyam/pptx2txt