# How to search a string in a pdf file

Tags: lucene.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to index pdf, ppt, xl files in lucene (java based or python or php any of these is fine)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582951/how-to-index-pdf-ppt-xl-files-in-lucene-java-based-or-python-or-php-any-of-th)

I need to search a string in a collection of files in a folder includes the pdf, docx, txt formats. Is it possible to search a string using lucene.net.

please give some references helpful for this..

thank u..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to extract the text of the various files (pdf, docx, txt) and insert that text into a that to a Lucene index. Lucene doesn't have the ability to read text out of the various document formats

- [Extract PDF text in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14170/Extract-Text-from-PDF-in-C-100-NET)
- [Docx and Ifilters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011234/how-to-extract-text-from-ms-office-documents-in-c-sharp)

Generally search for "extract {document format} text in .net" and you should find plenty of resources.